# Multidimensional array JQUERY and JSON

Tags: jquery, json, multidimensional-array

Ok..so i have a json string (myJson) that looks like this:

```
{"id": "1", "file": "test.jpg"}
```

and in my jquery function, I want to put these id and file values of my json string to an item in an array.

so, i have

```
var myArray = new Array();
var parsedJson = $.parseJSON(myJson);
myArray['item1']['id'] = parsedJson.id;
myArray['item1']['file'] = parsedJson.file;
```

but even after the execution of these codes, the length of the array `myArray` remains **zero**. Could somebody explain me why this is happening?

Comment: first of all this is not multidimensional array..this is basic json string

Comment: yeah...but i want to put the values from the parsed JSON string into a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you're confusing PHP associative arrays with JavaScript arrays. In JavaScript, you have objects instead of associative arrays and they behave differently. You can try one of the following approaches depending on your needs:

```
var myArray = {};
var parsedJson = $.parseJSON('{"id": "1", "file": "test.jpg"}');
myArray['item1'] = {};
myArray['item1']['id'] = parsedJson.id;
myArray['item1']['file'] = parsedJson.file;
myArray['item2'] = {};
myArray['item2']['id'] = parsedJson.id + '_2';
myArray['item2']['file'] = parsedJson.file + '_2';
console.log(myArray);
```

Or this:

```
var myArray = [];
var parsedJson = $.parseJSON('{"id": "1", "file": "test.jpg"}');
myArray.push({
    id: parsedJson.id,
    file: parsedJson.file
});
myArray.push({
    id: parsedJson.id + '_2',
    file: parsedJson.file + '_2'
});
console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: I will give these a try ..thank you very much for your reply. I am very new to javascript.:)

Answer (score 1):

You code can be rewritten simply like this

```
myArray['item1'] = {"id": "1", "file": "test.jpg"};
```

This code will produce the sample result.

You got the length of "myArray" = 0 because in this case, "item1" is a property of object myArray. It is not an element of myArray.

Please read this for more information about "Objects as associative arrays"
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"id": "1", "file": "test.jpg"}');
alert( obj.id );
alert (obj.file)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2TWdQ/)

Answer (score 0):

this works perfectly:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"id": "1", "file": "test.jpg"}');
alert( obj.id );
alert (obj.file);
```

but  it breaks down when i send a multidimensional array created in php, the code i´m using is written below:

(jquery)

```
function actualizarIndex(){ 
    /* RECOGEMOS LAS VARIABLES */
    $.post('php/consulta-actualizar-index.php', 
        { arriendoConsulta: 'arriendo'}
        ,
        function(data) {
            var parsedJson = $.parseJSON(data);
            alert(parsedJson);
            alert(parsedJson.tipoInmueble);

        }).error(
            function(){
        console.log('Error al ejecutar la petición');
        }
    );

}
```

(php)

```
$actArriendo = $_POST["arriendoConsulta"];

//insertamos el inmueble con todas las opciones recbidas
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `recomendados-integridad` WHERE `negocio`= '$actArriendo'";
$inmueble = mysql_query($sql, $conexion) or die(mysql_error());

$i = 0;

if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($inmueble)){ 

   do { 
        echo "<hr><br>conteo: " . $i ."<br>";
        ${'camposInmuebleInicio'.$i} = array(
            'tipoInmueble' => $row['tipoInmueble'],
            'negocio' => $row['negocio'],
            'alcobas' => $row['alcobas'],
            'banos' => $row['banos'],
        );

        ++ $i;
       } 
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($inmueble)); 


} else { 
echo "¡ No se ha encontrado ningún registro !"; 
}


$casasArriendoArray = array( $camposInmuebleInicio0 ,  $camposInmuebleInicio1 , $camposInmuebleInicio2);
$json = json_encode( $casasArriendoArray );
echo $json;
```